# iOS - scrubber bar is hide while scroll to next page using PSPDFkit framework version 7 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit

In iOS app, While scrolling pdf page, scrubber bar ( PSPDFThumbnailBarModeScrubberBar ) is hide and not appearing again using  PSPDFKit version 7 for iOS - Objective C.

Please help...Thanks.

Comment: PSPDFKit offers a support ticket platform at https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/ both for customers evaluating the license and for license holders. We recommend reaching out for any questions you might have with using it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it might be help others if facing same issue.

Just set builder configuration property as "shouldHideUserInterfaceOnPageChange = NO"

This property is by default YES.

Comment: Documentation is here: https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFConfiguration.html#/c:objc(cs)PSPDFConfiguration(py)shouldHideUserInterfaceOnPageChange